# Https rest request error for "failure to open file" in oracle

Tags: oracle, https, oracle-apex

I need help...

I'm try use apex_web_service.make_rest_request function but i'm not succesfull.

I believe, that this problem is permission in my wallet folder, but I add permission for Everyone, but not fix the problem.

My request is follow:

```
select apex_web_service.make_rest_request(
    p_url         => 'https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_day.geojson', 
    p_http_method => 'GET',
    p_wallet_path => 'file:D:\https_wallet'    ) from dual;
```

My wallet directory in Windows SO is D:\https_wallet.

This directory was automatically created by orapki tool with command:

```
orapki wallet create -wallet https_wallet -pwd <MyPasswordWallet> -auto_login
```

And add certificates of the site as a follow:

orapki wallet add -wallet D:\https_wallet -cert D:\TEMP\DigiCert.cer -trusted_cert -pwd 
orapki wallet add -wallet D:\https_wallet -cert D:\TEMP\DigicertSH2.cer -trusted_cert -pwd

After this commands the massage "The operation successful" is show to me.

But if I'm try the request the massage return is:

```
ORA-28759: falure to open file
ORA-06512: em "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 380
ORA-06512: em "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1148
```

Answer (score 0):

askmax.solution help me to solved my problem.

Is simple, is not sufficient add permission in folder wallet.

Is necessary add permission in files "cwallet.sso" and "ewallet.p12" to. After add permission directly in this files my function return the json of site request.